# Flutter iOS build on the App Center fails with error: "Invalid Podfile file: Generated.xcconfig must exist

Tags: ios, flutter, visual-studio-app-center

I've just set up my app to be built on the App Center, by following the [article here](https://www.rocksolidknowledge.com/articles/using-appcenter-for-flutter-projects).

Although the Android version builds and deploys fine on App Center, I'm getting an error with the iOS build, shown in the excerpt from the build output below:

```
==============================================================================
Task         : CocoaPods
Description  : Install CocoaPods dependencies for Swift and Objective-C Cocoa projects
Version      : 0.151.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/cocoapods
==============================================================================
[command]/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/pod --version
1.9.1
[command]/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/pod install --repo-update

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first.

 #  from /Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/work/1/s/bdstories/ios/Podfile:51
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #      unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
 >        raise "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
 #      end
 #  -------------------------------------------
##[error]The process '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/pod' failed with exit code 1
##[error]The 'pod' command failed with error: The process '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/pod' failed with exit code 1
##[section]Finishing: Pod install
##[section]Starting: Xcode build (signed)
```

My build script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Place this script in project/ios/.

# Fail if any command fails.
set -e

# Debug log.
set -x
cd ..

git clone -b beta https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
export PATH=`pwd`/flutter/bin:$PATH

flutter channel beta
flutter doctor

echo "Installed flutter to `pwd`/flutter"

# Build the app.
flutter build ios --release --no-codesign
```

I did add the `flutter pub get` as mentioned in the error, but that didn't make a difference. Also worth noting that the build works fine when I do it in Xcode locally. I can also deploy the built archive to Testflight with no problems. It's just the App Center build process I'm having issues with.

I'm a bit lost now and I can't find any information on how to resolve this. I'm also new to CI/CD, so any help appreciated!

**Update**

I've also tried adding the following to the script to force App Center to run the same version of Cocoapods as my local machine, but it didn't make a difference to the error.

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.9.1
pod setup
```

Comment: Did you ever come up with a resolution for this? I'm running into the exact same issues and I've tried all the same things

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately. I'll be looking at it again in the coming days though. The App Center support guys say they'll pass the info on, but as it's not officially supported, they can't promise anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this to my post-clone script and it worked:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#Place this script in project/ios/

echo "Uninstalling all CocoaPods versions"
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods --all --executables

COCOAPODS_VER=`sed -n -e 's/^COCOAPODS: \([0-9.]*\)/\1/p' Podfile.lock`

echo "Installing CocoaPods version $COCOAPODS_VER"
sudo gem install cocoapods -v $COCOAPODS_VER

# fail if any command fails
set -e
# debug log
set -x

pod setup

cd ..
git clone -b beta https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
export PATH=`pwd`/flutter/bin:$PATH

flutter channel master
flutter doctor
flutter pub get

echo "Installed flutter to `pwd`/flutter"

flutter build ios --release --no-codesign
```

The trick seems to have been moving the "fail if any command fails" section to after the pod re-installation

Comment: I add it but unfortunately error message remains.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. It happens when the appcenter-post-clone.sh fails to run, so, the flutter is not installed and the command `flutter build ios` does not run to generate the `Generated.xcconfig`.

To fix it, I just:

- Deleted the `appcenter-post-clone` and pushed this commit
- Opened the configuration of the branch, on Build section. Now the post-clone tag has gone. Save it.
- Push another commit with the appcenter-post-clone.sh again.
- Configure the branch again, now with the post-clone tag back.
- Save & Build.

Comment: This solved my ploblem. I also commented `Generated.xcconfig` in the `.gitignore` from `ios` folder. But i think it would work without changing `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 2):

1- Navigate to the flutter module directory
2- Do a flutter pub get
** Also make sure that you are on the stable channel "Flutter"

Answer (score 1):

Check your .gitIgnore. Had the same issue due to the file being excluded from the repo.

Once added back everything went fine.

Be also careful on the Paths defined for Flutter in your project.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I had to do this for the Android App Center build, which works fine, but what specific files do I need to remove from .gitignore for an iOS build to work?

Comment: This link explains everything, follow the steps, and tell me if you still have issues!

https://medium.com/codespace69/common-mistakes-when-writing-a-flutter-app-errors-collection-part-1-2d40abfcea2f

Comment: When answering questions on Stack Overflow, It's better to link to the source AND provide the relevant information in the answer. I cannot read that article due to being over the limit on Medium for the month - and from the title, it doesn't even sound relevant to my issue with the App Centre CI/CD  setup.

Comment: To fix that issue you need to comment the Generated.xcconfig in the .gitIgnore.
This will resolve that issue.
If then you will run in other issue, then probably the project was generated incorrectly, like happened to me. In my case this was due to the use of VSCode instead of Android studio. This fixed all the issues in my project.

Comment: The generated.xcconfig is excluded in .gitgnore, as it's designed to be generated during the build process, whether it's on your machine or built by App Center. Having said that, one of the things I did do as a test was to remove it from gitignore, to see what would happen. As expected, it came up with a whole set of other problems due to the paths therein (which were only relevant to my machine). Editing the file is not a good idea either, as it would get overwritten each time I did a build locally to test. So, not a good solution!

Comment: You are using VSCode or Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to work now. I think there's been an update to the App Center build process.
For your info, I've included my final post-build script below, in case this is useful:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#Place this script in project/ios/

# fail if any command fails
set -e
# debug log
set -x

cd ..
git clone -b beta https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
export PATH=`pwd`/flutter/bin:$PATH

flutter channel beta
flutter doctor

echo "Installed flutter to `pwd`/flutter"

flutter build ios --release --no-codesign
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue after I copied an existing build profile from another branch. The problem was resolved after deleting the build config and creating a new one from scratch for the target branch.

Answer (score -3):

Try to enter the IOS folder then `pod install`or 
`pod update`

in the terminal

Comment: Like I mentioned, this issue is not local to my machine, which builds fine. It's on the App Center build process.